# Simple Picture based App

Tags: ipad

I'm developing a iPad app which is just a series of pictures, and I'm stuck. I've managed to link up a Tab Bar Contoller to the 6 View Controllers and all seems to work well. But I'd like to be able swipe to the next View Controller once the user has selected the button. How do I do this? The swipe gestures don't work for me. Here's a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you outline the flow of what you're trying to achieve in a little more detail? Right now, it sounds like you want it to go something like: user selects tab item, nothing happens, user can then swipe to next view.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that when the app opens there are 6 tab buttons on the bottom.. when the user clicks on one of the tabs it opens a picture ..(that part seems to work as you can see in the pic above) .. but then I would like the user to be able to swipe to the next series of pics... double tapping any of the pics would return the user to the home page ... (which is at the top of the pic attached) ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `UIPageController`. This is the control that is used in the iPhone Weather app to allow you to swipe from city to city. Go [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see the full documentation on the control.

Comment: Thanks woz ... will have a look ... I emailed you from your web site ... if you you like to help in developing this app we can chat ... cheers

Comment: I don't have a website. Who is this app for?

Answer (score 0):

That's not usually how Tab Bars work in iOS, but…

What it sounds like you're after is either a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) with paging enabled (keep in mind you'll have to set the scroll view's `ContentSize`) or a [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) (if you don't want to deal with sizing explicitly and you're OK making a new UIViewController to house each image). I'd recommend the first option. The process would go something like:

1. Add the `UIScrollView` as a subview of your main view (remember, ensure to set `pagingEnabled` to `YES`
2. Add each image to the scroll view
3. Set the scroll view's content size to the total width of all images

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Also note that if you use the tab bar control (I recommend against it for UX purposes), you will probably need to watch the scroll/page view and update the selected tab in the tab bar accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ... I'll check it out ... in one way I feel this all a bit beyond me ... I've tried the Indian route to get a developer but it's been so painful.. if anybody is will to take up the task I'm happy to pay ... it will be a real simple app .. I've even set up a blank project (no pic's) all I need to get done is the navigation part...
Cheers Les

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a full-time job that keeps me pretty busy. You may want to look elsewhere if you're looking to hire someone to build this app for you. 

Also, if this answer was helpful to you, please accept it as correct. Thanks!